# Compile collectible assembly from CodeCompileUnit

Tags: c#, codedom

How I can compile [**collectible assembly**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554932.aspx) from `CodeCompileUnit`?

Answer (score 1):

From the page you linked:

> Reflection emit is the only mechanism that is supported for loading collectible assemblies. Assemblies that are loaded by any other form of assembly loading cannot be unloaded.

Since CodeDOM isn't using Reflection.Emit, I think that means you can't create collectible assembly from `CodeCompileUnit`.